# Excel Line Spacing within a single cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

Supposedly this is the data of a Single Cell A1:

```
Score     Remarks
1-10     25
  25-38      jk
 100-150   merry
```

I need a shortcut where I can Allign in such a way that the spacing between the data is uniform.

```
Score     Remarks
1-10      25
25-38     jk
100-150   merry
```

I need it like this. NOTE: Do not suggest to use SpaceBars in between, What if the data is huge?

Comment: You will need to split on the line return and then trim to remove the extra spaces, then split that on the space and count the number in the first then concantenate the two back together with a number of spaces that will align the second part using a certain number of spaces minus the length of the first part.  This will take vba and this is not a code for me site.  Also you will need to use a monospace font or you will never be able to make it work.  It would be best to split it into new cells.  It would be easier to align.

Comment: If the cell has combined Data you cannot calculate or use it easily

Comment: Welcome to the site. This is a Q&A site, not a service forum. Please [edit] you post to include what you have already tried and what the results were. We will try to help from there.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following user defined function:

```
Public Function PrettyOutput(sIN As String) As String
    Dim hr As String, i As Long, maxL As Long
    Dim U As Long

    hr = Chr(10)
    If InStr(1, sIN, hr) = 0 Then
        PrettyOutput = sIN
        Exit Function
    End If

    ary = Split(sIN, hr)
    U = UBound(ary)
    For i = 0 To U
        ary(i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(ary(i))
    Next i

    maxL = 0
    For i = 0 To U
        bry = Split(ary(i), " ")
        If Len(bry(0)) > maxL Then maxL = Len(bry(0))
    Next i

    For i = 0 To U
        bry = Split(ary(i), " ")
        PrettyOutput = PrettyOutput & bry(0) & Application.WorksheetFunction.Rept(" ", maxL - Len(bry(0))) & " " & bry(1) & hr
    Next i
    PrettyOutput = Mid(PrettyOutput, 1, Len(PrettyOutput) - 1)
End Function
```

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=myfunction(A1)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

Macros must be enabled for this to work!

So with data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=PrettyOutput(A1)
```

and format **B1** with a font like *Courier*:

[image]

Comment: Oh wow, nice! ...just a comment, I know OP asked for all in a single cell, seeing this all in a single cell makes me shudder, haha.  In the future (@Hussain) I suggest looking in to make this data available in separate cells. It'll make manipulating the data much easier and is actually a "better" way to use Excel.

Comment: @BruceWayne  I agree with you...it is unfortunate that this alignment task can't be accomplished with *Tab* characters.

Answer (score 0):

Data -> Text to columns is what it sounds like you want. Don't try to keep everything in one cell, split it up among several cells.